# How to know what differences that "git push" is going to push?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

After I have git add, and git commit, my workspace, index cached, and local repository became the same. So how can I know when I "push", what differences are there in this patch set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In conjunction with [git-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

```
git diff origin/master [ <local-branch-name> ]
```

you might be looking for

```
git push --dry-run --verbose
```

This will simulate a push and print all information you need on the way. From the [git man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

```
git-push:
-v
--verbose

    Run verbosely.

-n
--dry-run

    Do everything except actually send the updates.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try `git diff origin/remote-branch-name..local-branch-name` or `git log -p origin/branch-name..local-branch-name`.

If you want to compare the current branch you are on, then you can leave off the local-branch name i.e. `git diff origin/remote-branch-name..`, `git log -p origin/branch-name..`.

Answer (score 1):

[Rashmirathi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40926983/1256452) is correct (and upvoted) but there is a key point obscured here:  When you run `git push`, you don't send *patches*, you send *complete commits*.

Here's a simple example:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ git clone upstream.git downstream
Cloning into 'downstream'...
done.
$ cd downstream
$ echo 'add stuff to the readme file' >> README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m 'make a mistake'
[master 20caf72] make a mistake
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now we have a commit we don't want, so we un-do the change we did (I could simply `git revert HEAD` but I want to do it a more complicated way).

```
$ ed README
48
$d
w
19
q
```

(this deletes the last line of file `README`)

```
$ git add README
$ git commit -m 'un-make the mistake'
[master b0ebc79] un-make the mistake
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
```

(we are now ready to push)

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 440 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To [path]/upstream.git
   49c7832..b0ebc79  master -> master
$
```

Even though there was no actual change at all, I still just pushed two commits.  Let's go over to the upstream (bare) repository and see:

```
$ cd ../upstream.git
$ git log --oneline
b0ebc79 un-make the mistake
20caf72 make a mistake
49c7832 initial
```

Indeed, there they are.

The right question is thus not "what patches will I send" but rather "what *commits* will I send".  Most of the time this does not make that much difference, but if you accidentally commit a 4 gigabyte video file, then commit a removal of that same file, the *diff* from "what they have" to "your newest commit" may be tiny, while the *commits you will send* include one very big one.

There's one other slightly obscure point, which is that your `origin/master` (or `origin/branch` if you are working on your `branch`) is based on *your* Git's *most recent knowledge* about the other, upstream Git's branches.  It's possible that something else has changed upstream.  If so, do you want to see it, or do you want to ignore it?  If you *do* want to see it, you will have to choose *how* you want to see it—and at some point you are likely to *have* to stop ignoring it.

To update your own Git's idea of what is on the other Git, you can run `git fetch origin`, which brings over anything new *they* have that you don't, and then updates your `origin/master`, `origin/branch`, and so on.  If they have nothing new, `git fetch` brings over nothing and updates nothing.  All of the `origin/*` names exist just so that your Git can tell you "this is what I found in the other Git, the last time I talked with it."

When you run:

```
git log -p origin/master..master
```

you are instructing your Git to look at commits that are on your `master` that are not on your `origin/master`.  That's *your* `origin/master`—so it's only as up to date as your most recent `git fetch`.

#### Key take-aways

1. Git sends and receives *commits*, not patches.  Git can make patches for you, so that you can email them, but `fetch` and `push` work on commits.
2. Use `git log` to view commits.  Add `-p` to view ordinary (non-merge) commits as patches: Git will make them for you, on the spot, just so that you can see them.  Add `--oneline` instead to just see the commit *subject* lines.

   The `log` command shows you commits starting from the place you name, or from your `HEAD` if you don't name anything.  It keeps going until it runs out of commits, or stops when it hits a commit you've told it to stop at.  That's what `origin/master..master` is about.  It tells `git log`:  "Start from my `master`, and stop when you reach my `origin/master`."  The two dots are required here.
3. Use `git diff` to compare two commits: `git diff origin/master master`, for instance.  You can spell this as `git diff origin/master..master` if you prefer—but watch out, because `git diff` simply compares the *end points*, skipping over all the commits in the middle.  If you accidentally committed a big movie file, then removed it, `git diff` will skip right over that (but `git log` won't!).
4. Use `origin/master` and other `origin/*` names to see what your Git remembers from the last time it got these from the other Git.
5. Run `git fetch` (or `git fetch origin`) to get your Git to talk to the other Git again and pick up anything new.  If the other Git is very active, you might need to do this often.  If it's pretty quiet, or is your own personal GitHub repository, you might *never* need to do this (because your Git also updates your own `origin/master` and the like on a successful `git push`).